# How real-time is the Podio Push Service?

Tags: podio

Does anyone know how "real-time" I can expect to receive notifications from the [Podio Push Service](https://developers.podio.com/examples/push)? Should I reliably expect notifications on the order of seconds, or minutes?

I am wondering, because Podio Webhooks might not be real-time enough for my purposes, so I'm looking for another solution. From [Podio](https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks):

> Call to web hooks are put on our low priority queue, meaning that they will usually be invoked immedidately, but in peak times there can be a delay of a few seconds or even minutes. On very rare occasions a webhook call can be delayed as much as 30 minutes

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you could normally expect notifications to show up immediately or within a few seconds. The delay (if any) has never been an issue for me.